# How does Power BI knows which rows are latest?

Tags: powerbi

I am using Power BI and my dataset with SQL Azure.

I created a products view which has (ProductId, Name, Status) columns.

When I refresh dataset in Power BI does it only import modified rows or all rows from SQL Azure?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the information found [here (Understanding data refresh section)](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-refresh-data/):

> When you refresh data, you are updating the data in the dataset that is stored in Power BI from your data source. This refresh is a full refresh and not incremental.

The refresh is a full refresh not incremental.  Since you are using an Azure SQL DB, you may want to try switching to "Direct Query" if possible.  This would eliminate the need for any data refresh, the queries will be executed directly against the data source.

Hope this helps.